# Firefox compatible CSS3 animation

Tags: css

I'm trying to convert this CSS3 webkit animation to be cross-browser compatible - mainly in Firefox.

It appears that the CSS3 elements are supported but I've had no luck. Any advice would be appreciated please!

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/UlLIcnQRAsjY5CGEvKxq?p=catalogue

```
  .site__title {
    color: #f35626;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(92deg,#f35626,#feab3a);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-animation: hue 60s infinite linear;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(92deg,#f35626,#feab3a);
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
-moz-animation: hue_m 60s infinite linear;
  }

@-webkit-keyframes hue {
  from {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

 @-moz-keyframes hue_m{
                from { -moz-filter: hue-rotate(0deg); }
                to { -moz-filter: hue-rotate(-360deg); }
            }
```

Comment: Check this MDN to see what filters are supported, `hue-rotate` is not one of them: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter

Comment: @somethinghere I can see it half way down the page listed?

Comment: Me too, the larger problem is that `background-clip: text` is not supported in FF

Comment: @PhilHudson sorry I must have glanced over it. Ignore that.

Comment: @Kyle, I'll drop background-clip:text that's not an issue. Thanks though!

Comment: Ok, your animation won't work properly without it though in that context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox does not support prefixed keyframes, only the official syntax, so this will work for all others browsers than Safari (or `-webkit-`):

```
@keyframes hue_m {
    from { 
        -moz-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
        -ms-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
        filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
    }
    to { 
        -moz-filter: hue-rotate(-360deg);
        -ms-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
        filter: hue-rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
```

See the description for keyframes on MDN here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes